# EncodeToPNG hangs the script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, texture2d

What I want is to read png file as byte[] array. I need that array in order to send it to the remote server via HTTP POST request. My code looks like this:

```
Sprite sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/" + _filename);
print("Sprite loaded.");
print("Texture size: " + sprite.texture.width + ", " + sprite.texture.height);
byte[] bytes = sprite.texture.EncodeToPNG();
print("Done.");
```

Logs look like this (I ran the app in unity editor):

```
Sprite loaded. 
Texture size: 750, 1334
```

It never prints "Done". I've waited several minutes. There are no errors in unity console.
File is about 1MB so it's not a huge photo. It looks like sprite is loaded without a problem, but it can't be converted to byte[] array (as png).
What's going on?

Comment: Add try-catch to the code. Maybe it will help to detect some error ```try { byte[] bytes = sprite.texture.EncodeToPNG(); } catch (ex) { print(ex); } print("Done.");```

Comment: Btw do you need to go through `Sprite`? You could directly load the image as `Texture2D` right?

Comment: Also don't use `Resources` at all! Rather directly drag your texture into `public Texture2D texture;` via the Inspector

Answer (score 1):

@KingGary thanks for the hint!

I've never thought that it'll raise an exception while using try-catch when there's none without it.

The exception is:

```
System.ArgumentException: Texture 'test_image' is not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the Texture Import Settings.
```

The solution is to select the file in the unity editor and enable "Read/Write Enabled" in the properties window.